# c# process.Kill() - остаётся иконка в трее

Tags: c#, system-tray

К примеру, есть приложение, которое свернуто в трее.

После закрытия процесса с помощью `process.Kill();`

В трее, остаётся иконка, но, как только ты наводишь на нёё курсором, она исчезает.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при завершении процесса исчезала так же и иконка с трея ?

Я так понимаю нужно что-то типа обновления трея ?

Comment: для начала попробовать использовать не `.Kill()`, а `.CloseMainWindow()`

Comment: Отлично, сработало, по чему-то и не знал о его существовании.

Comment: @ГеннадийП можно было оформить ответом

Comment: @webstackoverload Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 3):

Для процессов, имеющих GUI-окно лучше использовать метод [.CloseMainWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow). Т.к. этот метод посылает команду на закрытие, то процесс корректно завершается с удалением иконки из трея.

Comment: А что делать, если после выполнения CloseMainWindow() окно в TaskBar действительно закрывается, но, программа уходит в трей ?

Comment: CloseMainWindow() посылает сигнал на закрытие главного окна как будто вы нажали крестик на окне, но некоторые программы могут его перехватывать, скрываясь в трей, выдавая запрос на подтверждение выхода и т.п. Выход - настроить программу чтобы она закрывалась, а не использовала скрытие в трей. Либо использовать Kill() но тогда значок в трее не исчезнет.

Comment: Программа - стороняя, поведение её именно такое как вы описали. При закрытии, прячется обратно в трей, хотя видно, что окно с taskbar было закрыто.  Что ж, выход действительно тогда один, ибо не хочется лезть в дебри типа обновления трея и т д.

Comment: Как вариант. Запомнить координаты положений значков в трее, и после Kill() через эмуляцию движения мышки быстренько пройтись по всем значкам, затем вернуть мышь на прежнее место. Как двигать мышь в C# гуглится без проблем.

Comment: Хотелось бы без всяких - замудрений и костылей.

Comment: Ещё вопрос, можно ли как-то открыть-отобразить запущенный софт в таксбаре ? Допустим софт уже висит в таксбаре, мы с помощью с# посылаем - если процесс есть, показать его в таксбаре ?